# Redirection during ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX/jQuery. I have 2 buttons. On each button click I need to send an AJAX request to server. But also during this process, I have to check if user is signed in or not. If the user is not signed in he should be redirected to the login page and after login he should come back to same page. Also in AJAX call the application which is specified in URL checks if user is signed in or not and redirects him to login page.The application contains the function to build the URL for login page. If user is already signed in then an another function will be called in application. The problem I am facing now is success function is not getting called when I run the whole project. Instead the error function is called. But if I pass the parameters to URL as query parameters then I am getting redirected to login page.

eg:www.abc.com/application?X=1&Y=2

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      X:param1,
      Y:param2,
    },
    url: "/application",
    success: function(data, status)
    {
      if (data.redirect) {
        window.location.href = data.redirect;
      } else {
        alert("success message");
      }
    },
    error:function()
    {
      alert("error message")
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This could be a problem in your URL rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

data.redirect will work assuming data is a json object.
To make sure add
    dataType: "json",
to the above and it should work.
Use Chromes Network panel to check if the server is talking back correctly.
Also check what Mime-Type it is returning. should be 'application/json'.

Error Function fires when the request is unsuccessful.
It takes 3 arguments but the 2nd is a Error String can be "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror".

Try this instead and you may find more debug info;

```
{
  $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           data: {
                  X:param1,
                  Y:param2,
               },
           url: "/application",
           success: function(data, status)
           {
             if (data.redirect) {
               window.location.href = data.redirect;
             } else {
               alert("success message");
             }
           },
           error:function(jqXHR, text)
           {
             alert("error message: "+text);
           }
    });
```

}